# Detecting an image 404 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, dom-events

After a user uploads a file we have to do some additional processing with the images such as resizing and upload to S3. This can take up to 10 extra seconds. Obviously we do this in a background. However, we want to show the user the result page immediately and simply show spinners in place until the images arrive in their permanent home on s3.

I'm looking for a way to detect that a certain image failed to load correctly (404) in a cross browser way. If that happens, we want to use JS to show a spinner in it's place and reload the image every few seconds until it can be successfully loaded from s3.

Comment: IIRC, there is an onerror event for images... http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/10916.asp

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: @Dorathoto why the bounty? The most upvoted answer is the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019077/detecting-an-image-404-in-javascript#answer-3019099

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From: [http://lucassmith.name/2008/11/is-my-image-loaded.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20120904060007/http://lucassmith.name/2008/11/is-my-image-loaded.html)

```
// First a couple helper functions
function $(id) {
    return !id || id.nodeType === 1 ? id : document.getElementById(id);
}
function isType(o,t) {    return (typeof o).indexOf(t.charAt(0).toLowerCase()) === 0;}

// Here's the meat and potatoes
function image(src,cfg) {    var img, prop, target;
    cfg = cfg || (isType(src,'o') ? src : {});

    img = $(src);
    if (img) {
        src = cfg.src || img.src;
    } else {
        img = document.createElement('img');
        src = src || cfg.src;
    }

    if (!src) {
        return null;
    }

    prop = isType(img.naturalWidth,'u') ? 'width' : 'naturalWidth';
    img.alt = cfg.alt || img.alt;

    // Add the image and insert if requested (must be on DOM to load or
    // pull from cache)
    img.src = src;

    target = $(cfg.target);
    if (target) {
        target.insertBefore(img, $(cfg.insertBefore) || null);
    }

    // Loaded?
    if (img.complete) {
        if (img[prop]) {
            if (isType(cfg.success,'f')) {
                cfg.success.call(img);
            }
        } else {
            if (isType(cfg.failure,'f')) {
                cfg.failure.call(img);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (isType(cfg.success,'f')) {
            img.onload = cfg.success;
        }
        if (isType(cfg.failure,'f')) {
            img.onerror = cfg.failure;
        }
    }

    return img;
}
```

And here how to use it:

```
image('imgId',{
    success : function () { alert(this.width); },
    failure : function () { alert('Damn your eyes!'); },
});

image('http://somedomain.com/image/typooed_url.jpg', {
    success : function () {...},
    failure : function () {...},
    target : 'myContainerId',
    insertBefore : 'someChildOfmyContainerId'
});
```

Comment: This raises a good point.  You (OP) need to load the images with random querystring parameters.

Comment: The link died. This answer should be amended to contain content or have it’s green tick taken away.

Comment: KISS (aka Keep It Super Simple)

Comment: I would change the isType function to a simple `typeof cfg.x==='function'`. It is more readable than 'f', and also faster - see here: http://jsperf.com/typeof-variations

Comment: This doesn't work if request returns HTTP 404 and fallback image

Answer (score 68):

Handle the `<img>` element's `onerror` event.

Comment: @xal: Just be sure to hook the `error` event *before* you set the `src` property (if you're doing this with `new Image` or `document.createElement("img")` rather than via an HTML string). Otherwise, you're in a race condition and the event could fire before you start handling it (just like the `load` event).

Comment: @T.J: Not necessarily. Javascript runs on the UI thread, so if you handle the event immediately after setting `src`, there shouldn't be any risk.  However, you're still right,

Comment: Javascript runs on the Javascript thread, which on *some browsers* is also the UI thread. It is not necessarily the download thread. I've helped people fix bugs caused by precisely this, setting `src` before setting a `load` handler. There's a race condition there. If you already have the handler registered, the event handling code will put it on the execution stack to be run once the JS thread is available to do something else. If you don't, you can miss the event.

Comment: Code examples for this: http://maisonbisson.com/post/12150/detecting-broken-images-in-javascript/

Comment: I'd like to comment on this, despite it being somewhat dated at this point, simply because it's a pretty popular question and answer. If an `<img>` returns a `404`, but the response includes an image (a placeholder image, for example), the `error` event will **not** be fired.

Comment: @TylerRoper is there a way to catch that 404 though? I'm dealing with that exact scenario

Answer (score 39):

**First option:**

```
<img src="picture1.gif" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='missing.gif';"/>
```

**Second option:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ImgError(source){
        source.src = "/noimage.gif";
        source.onerror = "";
        return true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="image_example1.jpg" onerror="ImgError(this)" />
</body>
</html>
```

PS: it's pure javascript! you don't need any libraries. (Vanilla JS)

**Example in Fidler**

https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/87wd6rjb/1/

Answer (score 11):

just bind the attr trigger on the error event.

```
$(myimgvar).bind('error',function(ev){
    //error has been thrown
    $(this).attr('src','/path/to/no-artwork-available.jpg');
}).attr('src',urlvar);
```

Comment: This assumes that all failed loads are 404's.

Comment: OP specifically said 404.

Answer (score 4):

I just did

```
if ($('#img')[0].naturalWidth > 0) {
```

as i noticed there was no naturalWidth if the image 404'd.

However, i can understand wanting to use a method above.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (mine is in coffeescript). You'll need to replace with a spinner instead, of course.

```
checkImages = ->
  $("img").each ->
    $(this).error ->
      $(this).attr("src", "../default/image.jpg")

$(document).on('page:load', checkImages)
```

I'm guessing the javascript equivalent is something like

```
function checkImages() {
  $("img").each(function() {
    $(this).error(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "../default/image.jpg");
    });
  });
};
```

$(document).on("page:load", checkImages);