# Detect 404 images using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I have in my application some references to Twitter photos.

When the photo is no longer available on Twitter side (see this example: http://p.twimg.com/AmL3hpaCEAd2wtN.jpg), I receive a 404 response code with an image as a body (the gray 404 image)

I'm using `onload` and `onerror` javascript methods on Img, but since p.twimg.com is returning a body, the `onload` method is triggered. I found no way to distinguish a 404 response from a 200 one.

Any idea?

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019077/detecting-a-image-404-in-javascript

Comment: Look at my updated answer, it may help.

Answer (score 3):

Check image size if it's 6.232bytes(Twitter not found image's size) or not.

[To find image file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, check my answer again.

Comment: I didn't think anything but this. The reason is already there, image is coming with no error.

Comment: You cannot use that method because the image is cross-origin. At best you can see the dimensions but not size in bytes.

Comment: Thanks, if possible I'd like to find a more sophisticated solution :)