# How can i call onerror() callback for an <object> SVG tag in Chome only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, callback

In chrome and Firefox the below issue doesn't work. it works in IE.

I have an element object which i create dynamically using JS:

```
svg = document.createElement("object");
    svg.setAttribute("type","image/svg+xml");
    svg.setAttribute("data",url);

mycanvas.appendChild(svg);
```

this successfully creates an object element with an svg inside it when i load a file that actually exists:
[image]

but when the file doesn't exist i get:

[image]

in which case i want to call an onerror() callback which i have created.

at the moment it looks like:

```
    svg.onerror = function() {
            alert("not found");
    };
```

but this onerror() doesn't get called because it looks for svg and svg is the object tag which is created regardless of the svg (image 2 above).

how can i check to see if the image is empty or non-existant (image 2 above) then call onerror.

i believe i need to something like:

```
var callback = document.getElementsByTagName("object")[0].contentDocument;
callback.onerror = function() {
    alert("not found");
};
```

the above fails but it was just a quick attempt i made.

any ideas?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used this helper function that enables us to detect also 404 error (wrong svg url): [Detecting an image 404 in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019077/detecting-an-image-404-in-javascript)

Look at the demo: it loads the Chrome logo as an SVG and draws it on the 1st canvas, and the same code with an wrong url alerts "error2"

```js
// First a couple helper functions
function $(id) {
    return !id || id.nodeType === 1 ? id : document.getElementById(id);
}
function isType(o,t) {    return (typeof o).indexOf(t.charAt(0).toLowerCase()) === 0;}

// Here's the meat and potatoes
function image(src,cfg) {    var img, prop, target;
    cfg = cfg || (isType(src,'o') ? src : {});

    img = $(src);
    if (img) {
        src = cfg.src || img.src;
    } else {
        img = document.createElement('img');
        src = src || cfg.src;
    }

    if (!src) {
        return null;
    }

    prop = isType(img.naturalWidth,'u') ? 'width' : 'naturalWidth';
    img.alt = cfg.alt || img.alt;

    // Add the image and insert if requested (must be on DOM to load or
    // pull from cache)
    img.src = src;

    target = $(cfg.target);
    if (target) {
        target.insertBefore(img, $(cfg.insertBefore) || null);
    }

    // Loaded?
    if (img.complete) {
        if (img[prop]) {
            if (isType(cfg.success,'f')) {
                cfg.success.call(img);
            }
        } else {
            if (isType(cfg.failure,'f')) {
                cfg.failure.call(img);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (isType(cfg.success,'f')) {
            img.onload = cfg.success;
        }
        if (isType(cfg.failure,'f')) {
            img.onerror = cfg.failure;
        }
    }

    return img;
}

// and here's how it's used:

url = "https://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120330024139/logopedia/images/d/d7/Google_Chrome_logo_2011.svg";

// first one that shows the image:
var mycanvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = image(url, {
  success:function(){ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);},
  failure:function(){alert("error1");}
});

// second one that has 404 error:
var mycanvas2 = document.getElementById("d");
var ctx2 = mycanvas2.getContext('2d');
var img2 = image("http://example.com/a.svg", {
  success:function(imga){ctx2.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);},
  failure:function(){alert("error2");}
});
```

```css
canvas{border: 1px solid #f00}
```

```html
c:<canvas id="c" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
d:<canvas id="d" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

Note, that technically this works not with an `object`, but an `img`, if I understood what is your intention then that shouldn't matter, because the goal is to draw it onto the canvas, and this code does exactly that.

Comment: Hi Gavriel, i tried this method now ..but for some reason it never enters the onerror() it always tries to load the image and when it cant i get 404 in the console but no alert. it skips the onerror() and goes to svg.setAttribute("data",url);

Comment: only in chrome and firefox it doesn't work. it works in IE

Comment: so i cannot use it when i am appending? because it works in IE but not in chrome and firefox.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I changed your code in a) using img instead of object, b) using ctx.drawImage instead of canvas.appendChild, so in my code you don't append. Visually IMHO the effect is the same, you'll see the image on the canvas. Test my code, and see if it fits your needs. I tested my code in Chrome only, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work in other browser.

Comment: unforunelty i have to use an object of type image/svg+xml that is an svg. i cant use image. i can do it with an image and it works fine. but thanks :)

Comment: @Sarah, I think there's a misunderstanding. Either I don't understand what and why you want to do or you don't understand that my code does the same as yours IMHO: I modified it to show that it works: it loads the Chrome logo as an SVG and draws it on the 1st canvas, and the same code with an wrong url alerts "error2". Isn't this what you want?

Comment: yes it is correct but i need the svg to be a part of an <object>. i dont think you used <Object> type image/svg+xml in your code example. otherwise it is working how i would like it too. but i need to implement it using <object>

Comment: Can you add a few sentences to the end of the question explaining what really are you trying to achieve and why do you need object for that?