# How to handle image not found error in html5 picture tag

Tags: html, image

I am trying to use the below piece of code:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="https://example.com/images/abc.jpg?resize=169,169">
    <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="https://example.com/images/cde.jpg?resize=132,132">
    <img src="index_files/red_1.jpg" alt="Red 1">
</picture>
```

the problem which I am facing is when abc.jpg or cde.jpg is not available it should show a default image say e.g., default.jpg and not even the red_1.jpg
I referred to other similar topic in the website but i didnt get to know how to handle the problem with the help of html.

Whether `onerror`could be used in that case, if yes, where and how?

Comment: This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18837735/8411228) could be helpful. But you need to use JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

```
<picture>
  <source srcSet="image.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <source srcSet="image.jpeg" type="image/jpeg" />
  <source srcSet="image.png" type="image/png" />
  <img srcSet="image.jpg" onError={(e) => {
    e.target.onerror = null;
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[0].srcset = e.target.src;
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[1].srcset = e.target.src;
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[2].srcset = e.target.src;
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[3].srcset = e.target.src;
  }} />
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [use the `onerror` event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3019099/3783155). Then, you can simply change the `src` attribute:

```
let image = document.querySelector('img');
image.onerror = function() {
  if (this.src === 'default1.png') this.src = 'default2.png';
  else if (this.src !== 'default2.png') this.src = 'default1.png';
}
```

This will change the `src` of the image from whatever it was to `'default1.png'` and then, if it fires again, to `'default2.png'`.

Comment: there are two <img> tag and the requirement is that - if 1st <img> tag has error then show default1.jpg and in case of 2nd <img> tag error, show default2.jpg.

Comment: i am unable to use your solution in my case.

Comment: @team I did edit my answer by simply adding an if-statement. It's just logic at this point