# Adding a 404 fallback for picture Tags in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, image, angular-directive

We are making heavy use of the [HTML5 `picture` Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp) in our Angular 9 Application. We now want to show a fallback image, when the actual src returns 404.

I created a directive that replaces the img src like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632999/2725515) suggests:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[fallbackSrc]',
})
export class FallbackImageDirective {
  constructor(
    @Attribute('fallbackSrc') public fallbackSrc: string,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {}

  @HostListener('error') onError() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', this.fallbackSrc);
  }
}
```

to work in picture tags:

```
<picture>
  <source
    *ngIf="_teaser.images.i377_212_webp"
    [srcset]="_teaser.images.i377_212_webp"
    type="image/webp"
  />
  <img
    loading="lazy"
    [alt]="_teaser.image_alt"
    [src]="_teaser.images.i377_212"
    fallbackSrc="/ng-assets/images/backgrounds/teaser_fallback_image.png"
    class="preview-image"
  />
</picture>
```

However, when I open the application, the request to the wepP-Image is made **over and over again**. I suspect that the browser notices the change in `<img src=` and starts evaluating the `<source>` tags again, then fails and `onError()` is called again, **resulting in an infinite loop**.

I also tried [this solution](https://medium.com/@sub.metu/angular-fallback-for-broken-images-5cd05c470f08) but it did just do nothing (maybe because it's for an older Angular version).

Is there anything I can do to stop the browser from evaluating the `source` Tags again?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by removing the `source` Tags inside the `onError` method:

```
@HostListener('error') onError() {
  const parentNode = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;

  if (parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'picture') {
    for (let child of parentNode.children) {
      if (child.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'source') {
        parentNode.removeChild(child);
      }
    }
  }

  this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', this.fallbackSrc);
}
```